# Minimum path Algorithm

Tags: java, algorithm

I know it's not quite a programming issue but a math problem instead but I'll hope someone of you could answer me :)

I'm looking for an algorithm that let me find minimum path across n points if I know all the distances between all the points.

For example: I have twelve points (A, B, C, ... H) and I know all the distances between couples of points (AB, BC, ..., GH, ecc...). If I want to go from A to H passing all the others points with the minimum path, wich way I need to take?

I know trying all the possible ways and choose the shortest isn't a good way (for 12 points you have 12! possible ways and I need to use this algorithm for more than 12 points...) but all the other algorithm I've found are too difficult to understand (like the Dijkstra one).

Can someone help me explaining me a way to implement a useful algorithm? I'm programming with Java but I don't know how I can write down the Dijkstra one (I can't understand it) and I haven't other ideas...

Comment: I think you would be best of to make the question "how to implement dijkstra's algorithm in java", instead of trying to find another solution?

Comment: The [Wiki article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dijkstra's_algorithm) about Dijkstra's algorithm has pseudo code. Perhaps you could give that a try and post back if you have a programming/implementation question?

Comment: Hmm, the "dijkstra" threw me off, but seeing the answer below mentioning the Traveling Salesman Problem: "from A to H passing all the others points with the minimum path" does indeed sound like the TSP, and not a shortest path

Comment: The Wiki article let you pass through the minimum path but not through all the points... I've tried to modify it but it seems hard...

Answer (score 2):

[Traveling Salesman Problem.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Travelling_salesman_problem)

Here is my solution (I know mine is brute force, but I just wanted to share my solution):

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.util.Locale;

import javax.swing.JSplitPane;

/* VPW Template */

public class Main
{

    /**
     * @param args
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException
    {
        new Main().start();
    }

    public float startX, startY;
    public int cityCount;
    public float citiesX[], citiesY[];
    public float distances[];
    public float shortest = Float.MAX_VALUE;

    public void start() throws IOException
    {
        /* Read the stuff */
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
        String[] input = new String[Integer.parseInt(br.readLine())];
        cityCount = input.length;
        citiesX = new float[input.length];
        citiesY = new float[input.length];
        for (int i = 0; i < input.length; ++i)
        {
            input[i] = br.readLine();
            String line = (input[i]);
            String[] lineElements = line.split(" ");
            float x = Float.parseFloat(lineElements[0]);
            float y = Float.parseFloat(lineElements[1]);
            citiesX[i] = x;
            citiesY[i] = y;
        }
        /* Read current position */
        String line = (br.readLine());
        String[] lineElements = line.split(" ");
        startX = Float.parseFloat(lineElements[0]);
        startY = Float.parseFloat(lineElements[1]);
        /* Compute distances */
        computeAllDistances();
        solve();
        System.out.println(String.format(Locale.US, "%.1f", shortest));
    }

    public void solve()
    {
        for (int i = 1; i <= cityCount; ++i)
        {
            boolean[] wentTo = new boolean[cityCount];
            wentTo[i - 1] = true;
            step(wentTo, i, distances[distanceIndex(0, i)]);
        }
    }

    public void step(boolean[] wentTo, int currentCity, float distance)
    {
        int wentToCount = 0;
        for (int i = 1; i <= cityCount; ++i)
        {
            if (wentTo[i - 1])
            {
                ++wentToCount;
                continue;
            }
            boolean[] copy = new boolean[cityCount];
            System.arraycopy(wentTo, 0, copy, 0, cityCount);
            copy[i - 1] = true;
            float dist = distance + distances[distanceIndex(currentCity, i)];
            step(copy, i, dist);
        }
        if (wentToCount == cityCount)
        {
            if (shortest > distance)
            {
                shortest = distance;
            }
        }
    }

    public void computeAllDistances()
    {
//      int count = (int) countDistances(cityCount + 1);
//      System.out.println("Compute Distances (" + count + ")");
        distances = new float[cityCount * cityCount];
        for (int i = 0; i <= cityCount; ++i)
        {
            for (int j = i + 1; j <= cityCount; ++j)
            {
                float x1, y1, x2, y2;
                if (i == 0)
                {
                    x1 = startX;
                    y1 = startY;
                } else
                {
                    x1 = citiesX[i - 1];
                    y1 = citiesY[i - 1];
                }
                x2 = citiesX[j - 1];
                y2 = citiesY[j - 1];
                float xDiff = x1 - x2;
                float yDiff = y1 - y2;
                float dist = (float) Math.sqrt(xDiff * xDiff + yDiff * yDiff);
//              System.out.printf("Distance (%d, %d)(%d) = %f\n", i, j, distanceIndex(i, j), dist);
                distances[distanceIndex(i, j)] = dist;
            }
        }
    }

    public int distanceIndex(int c1, int c2)
    {
        if (c1 == c2)
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Cities are the same! (" + c1 + ")");
        if (c1 < c2)
        {
            return c1 * cityCount + c2 - 1;
        } else
        {
            return c2 * cityCount + c1 - 1;
        }
    }

    public long countDistances(long l)
    {
        if (l == 0 || l == 1)
            return 0;
        return (l - 1) + countDistances(l - 1);
    }

}
```

Usage:

Input:

```
[number of cities]
[x] [y]     (city 0)
[x] [y]     (city 1)
[x] [y]     (city 2)
[x] [y]     (city 3)
.....
[x] [y]     (of your current position)
```

Output:

```
[The shortest distance you have to travel.]
```

---

Example:

Input:

```
11
3 3
7 1
4 4
2 10
40 2
15 9
7 13
16 23
8 0
4 8
10 10
5 10
```

Output:

```
83.2
```

Comment: This is interesting, because It looks like the question is actually about the TSP, and not the "shortest path" ?

Comment: This solution assumes that the order that you want to visit the cities is already set.  TSP makes no such order, so you'd have to do it for 2^n (exponential of number of cities) possible permutations, which makes this solution infeasible for TSP.

Comment: Thank you very much :) I'll analyze it and try to integrate to my program :)

Comment: Unfortunately I'm looking for a powerful way to retrieve minimum path... I've also tried to modify Wikipedia's one but it's very hard! Thank you for your help anyway!